Unable to control real UR5 when adding EndEffector
I am currently working with a (real) UR5 robot and am trying to use it as a manipulator for a customized end-effector which will be used to 3D print PLA. I will be moving this robot using MoveIt, visualize it using Rviz and I am using the using ur_robot_driver package to actually move the robot. I have succesfully done this by following the steps in this tutorial: https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/master/ur_robot_driver/doc/usage_example.md
So, the main body seems to work, but now I want to add an end-effector to the visualisation and also use this new TCP as the point which should move to a certain coordinate. This toolhead is called printhead and is a fully rigid body. To accommodate this this purpose I have added the end-effector to a .xacro file and made a new MoveIt package (ur5_apla_moveit_config). To further control the robot I have used a lot of inspiration from the ur5_moveit_config package, and basically kept everything the same EXCEPT the urdf/srdf/xacro file. Since well, the configuration is now different.
And well, even though I am able to successfully launch a Rviz of this new configuration (to verify that the urdf/xacro file is correct) I am not able to use this new MoveIt package to actually control the real robot. When launching the moveit_planning_execution.launch file from ur5_apla_moveit_config I keep getting:
[ERROR] [timecode]: Semantic description is not specified for the same robot as the URDF
Which is, so weird, since the srdf and urdf file are both called ur5_apla_with_printhead” But to make it even weirder, a few logs later it says Launching ur5_robot model, which is even weirder since this name ur5_robot is the generic name which is NOWHERE in my package… I feel like this is a hint that it is launching, somehow, the wrong model but I have no clue how and from where.
I added the full repository on https://github.com/90zaza/ROS-UR5-APLA, ur5_apla contains my generated xacro and urdf and ur5_apla_moveit_config contains the configuration and launch files I use to control the robot. The package universal_robot is purely in it to serve as example, it should have no connection whatsoever to the two ur5_apla... packages.
So to summarize, the sequence I want to work is the following. The semantic error comes on the second roslaunch snippet:
roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx kinematics_config:=/home/tim/ur5_calibration.yaml
roslaunch ur5_apla_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch → gives error
Thank you in advance for looking into it, at this point I am quite lost so all the help is much appreciated!

Please edit your question and explain to us how you have added/attached your new eef to the preexisting "eef_link" in the ur5 urdf (or upload the files to github and provide a url so we can see for ourselves.)

@Mike973, you are totally right. I have added the full workspace and edited the question

Your new End Effector Tool contains only fixed joints, which in effect means you are simply changing the shape of tool0 (and probably the pose of the tool0 frame.) From a moveit planning perspective, if you keep the eef name as tool0, you would only have to make a one-line change to modify the origin tag for the flange-tool0 joint in the urdf file.
Further, it makes no sense to declare a <group name="printhead"> for something without any controllable/moveable joints. This group definition provides no problem for moveit to solve for. This is because the pose of the tool0 frame is completely defined by the pose of the flange frame.
Your semantic error is most likely because your .srdf file does not match the .urdf file, i.e. the described links or joints differ between the two descriptions.

Thank you for looking into it. I have a couple of questions regarding your answer:

When using the one-line change, I feel like we then overwrite the definition of the tool0? Do we then see the "printhead" as a link?
I understand that a group tag is unnecessary, but does it provide no value to separate the different parts of the robot?
I do not understand how the .urdf and .srdf file do not match up, since the .srdf is generated by the MoveIt setup-assistant, based on the .urdf, how could they then not match? I also see no differences in described links or joints between them...

